# Next and Previous navigation

Tags: javascript, html, comparative-review, react.js, redux

I'm sorry, maybe this question is really stupid but I have really been thinking a lot about it recently, thinking of which type of `<prev | next>` web navigation approach is better. FYI the stack is React + Redux.

1. With using `name` properties (or also we can use something like custom `boolean` field `forward="ture"` and check it)

   HTML:

   ```
     <span>
         <button name="prev" onClick={this.onYearChange.bind(this)}>Prev</button>
         <div>{this.state.year}</div>
         <button name="next" onClick={this.onYearChange.bind(this)}>Next</button>
     </span>
   ```

   JS handler:

   ```
    onYearChange(e){
           let dir = (e.target.name === 'prev') ? -1 : 1,
               year = this.props.selectedYear + dir;

           this.props.onYearChangeHandler(year);
     }
   ```
2. With passing custom property `dir` with `inc/dec` value

   HTML:

   ```
   <span>
      <button dir={-1} onClick={this.onYearChange.bind(this)}>Prev</button>
      <div>{this.state.year}</div>
      <button  dir={1} onClick={this.onYearChange.bind(this)}>Next</button>
   </span>
   ```

   JS:

   ```
   onYearChange(e){
           let dir = e.target.dir,
               year = this.props.selectedYear + dir;

           this.props.onYearChangeHandler(year);
   }
   ```
3. Or with two separate binded functions

   HTML:

   ```
    <span>
        <button onClick={this.toPrevYear.bind(this)}>Prev</button>
        <div>{this.state.year}</div>
        <button onClick={this.toNextYear.bind(this)}>Next</button>
    </span>
   ```

   JS:

   ```
       toPrevYear(e) {
           this.onYearChange(-1);
       };

       toNextYear(e) {
           this.onYearChange(1);
       };

       onYearChange(val) {
           let year = this.props.selectedYear + val;

           this.props.onYearChangeHandler(year);
       }
   ```

Or is there some better solution for this scenario?

Comment: Can you make it work like ordinary `LINK` and `A` elements using the standard `REL="next"` etc attributes, so that browsers' usual navigation tools work?

Comment: @TobySpeight oh wellp, never tought about it. never done lot of `HTML` stuff. but still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think your worrying yourself about small details here, any advantages of one over the other would be minor at best.

I think out of all 3, the last solution would be my preferred one. It's clean from a code separation POV and does exactly what it says on the tin, also easier to change behaviour without affecting the other should that ever need to happen.

FWIW for performance reasons it's recommended you bind UI event handlers in the constructor e.g.

```
constructor() {
    this.toPrevYear = this.toPrevYear.bind(this);
}
...
render() {
    return <button onClick={this.toPrevYear}>Prev</button>;
}
```

Comment: oh thanks, i've been thinking about such proper separation stuff. but on other hand what makeds me hesitating that mostly its just simply all about inc/dec some parameter

Answer (score 2):

I agree with James that #3 is better because of the separation aspect.

I admit that I am a novice as far as React goes, having typically worked with other frameworks like jQuery, PrototypeJS, AngularJS, VueJS. The perspective below might not really meld well with traditional React techniques, but [Event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) really helps separate the event logic (JS) from the presentation/markup (HTML).

So consider HTML like this:

```
<span ref={(span) => this.linksContainer = span}>
    <button name="prev" className="pageLink">Prev</button>
    <div>{this.state.year}</div>
    <button name="next" className="pageLink">Next</button>
  </span>
```

Notice how the buttons don't need to worry about which function gets called - just that it contains the name (either *prev* or *next) as well as a class name.

Using that HTML, we could add an event delegate to listen for clicks on the element that contains the page links and look for the class name "pageLink". This is especially helpful when there are numerous elements on the page that all need to have a function bound to an event.

This may not be the best place for it, but my initial attempt is to add the delegate (i.e. a click handler, using [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the [*click*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event) in the *componentDidMount* method on the *linksContainer* element...

```
this.linksContainer.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this))
```

Then define that method:

```
clickHandler(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.classList.contains('pageLink')) {
       //the lines in this block could be moved to a separate method
       let dir = (clickEvent.target.name === 'prev') ? -1 : 1,
           year = this.props.selectedYear + dir;
        this.props.onYearChangeHandler(year);
    }
}
```

The code inside that conditional `if (clickEvent.target.classList.contains('pageLink')) {` could be moved to a separate method. And that click handler could also detect clicks on other elements and *delegate* to other functions

See an example in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/aelliott/pen/mMjwwz).

Comment: Yep, `addEventListener` is the ticket

Comment: interesting toughts, thanks :) +1 I'm too new to React, used ExtJS most of the time on my previous job, and there are almost no need of any HTML

Comment: This is really just a more roundabout way of doing the first option and probably less efficient as you need to wait for the event to propagate all the way up to the document before it gets handled. Furthermore, this could become a bit of a maintenance problem i.e. your at risk of introducing breaking changes because all your click handling would be in here. React promotes composition with the notion that components are self-contained (which should include event handlers etc.). I certainly wouldn't be hooking up events on the `document` unless I absolutely had to.

Comment: okay - I added a ref to the links container (i.e. `<span>`) so as to avoid using the `document` object. What do you think of that?

Answer (score 2):

#### About the HTML

As pagination is some form of navigation (i.e., links), you should use `a` elements instead of `button` elements.

This also allows you to use the [sequential link types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#sequential-link-types) `next` and `prev`.

```html
<a href="/foo" rel="prev">Previous</a>
<a href="/bar" rel="next">Next</a>
```